# How do make magento use a different category than 'Default Category' to generate the header-nav?

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, magento

I have 4 categories within the 'Default Category' category. Currently by default Magento is generating the header-nav from 'Default Category', and displaying the 4 categories at the top of my site.  The "Products" category is in the "Default Cateogry".  Inside the "Products" category are the sub categories that i want to have displayed on my top nav.

Default Category:

- Products
- Featured Products
- Popular Products
- Applications

The product/category setup is what was given to me on this project, which is what i want to make work without having to redo(as there are a couple hundred products already created). Had i started from scratch, the product/category setup would be different.

In app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php I found that the menu is generated using the function `getStoreCategories()`, which it would seem pulls everything from the 'Default Category' category.

So I guess I'm looking for 1 of 3 solutions:

1. A way from within the Magento admin to chose which category to use to generate the top menu.
2. Which function to use, that is not `getStoreCategories`, so I can specify the parent category, and modify app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php
3. Or is this something I can manipulate somewhere in the layout xml files along with a custom template piece if necessary.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the site's store setup, you can choose which "root" category to use as the store's category layout. Note that you may *only* choose root categories for this. Please modify your post with what your intention is here if you need further help in structuring your categories.

Head to System -> Manage Stores and click on one of the links under Store Name

Comment: Where is that option found? In the "catalog" or in "system" section?

Comment: Head to System -> Manage Stores and click on one of the links under Store Name.

Answer (score -1):

You can also specify the ID of the root category used for the main navigation by modifying the file situated in:

```
app > code > core > Mage > Catalog > Helper > Category.php
```

Looks for the function "getStoreCategories()" and change

```
$parent     = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
```

with your root category ID

```
$parent     = YOUR-ID;
```

Everything works fine for me with this trick.